# Mysql join table on latest record by time

Tags: mysql, database

Hello I have the following two tables which represents a document with its stage and a history table that shows the time document was moved to next stage

```
CREATE TABLE `document` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` text,
  `stage` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `customer_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creator_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `customer_city` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_state` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_zip` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_contact` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `number` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `longitude` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `creation_date` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expanded_description` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `document_history` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `doc_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `modifying_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `changed_to_stage` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `old_stage` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_modified` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I need to get count statistics based on selected period.For example I need to know how many documents were in stage 1 during selected period, but the problem is that if a document was in several different stages during this period - I have to count it only for the last stage, e.g. if doc was in stage 1 and after that in stage 2 - I need to count it only for stage 2.

Here is what I have till now:

```
SELECT 
round(sum(case when dh.modifying_time between '2016-09-15' and '2016-09-24' and dh.changed_to_stage = 1 then 1 else 0 end),0) entry_count,
round(sum(case when dh.modifying_time between '2016-09-15' and '2016-09-24' and dh.changed_to_stage = 3 then 1 else 0 end),0) pricing_count,
round(sum(case when dh.modifying_time between '2016-09-15' and '2016-09-24' and dh.changed_to_stage = 5 then 1 else 0 end),0) executed_count,
round(sum(case when dh.modifying_time between '2016-09-15' and '2016-09-24' and dh.changed_to_stage = 7 then 1 else 0 end),0) approved_count,
round(sum(case when dh.modifying_time between '2016-09-15' and '2016-09-24' and dh.changed_to_stage = 9 then 1 else 0 end),0) canceled_count
FROM document doc join document_history dh on doc.id=dh.doc_id
```

The problem here is that the document is counted twice if it was in two different stages in that period.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks and best regards

Comment: Please add sample data to reproduce. Also tell us the rule of putting records inside history table. Do you keep the actual record in history as well?

Comment: Record in history table is added when a document is created, also if a document is moved from stage to stage.

Answer (score 1):

You want to select just the *last* stage, then you can do the logic in the `where`.  But, I would suggest moving the date condition to the `WHERE` first and getting rid of `ROUND()` (for intengers?  really?):

```
SELECT sum(case when dh.changed_to_stage = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as entry_count,
       sum(case when dh.changed_to_stage = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as pricing_count,
       sum(case when dh.changed_to_stage = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as executed_count,
       sum(case when dh.changed_to_stage = 7 then 1 else 0 end) as approved_count,
       sum(case when dh.changed_to_stage = 9 then 1 else 0 end) as canceled_count
FROM document doc join
     document_history dh
     on doc.id = dh.doc_id 
WHERE dh.modifying_time between '2016-09-15' and '2016-09-24' and
      dh.modifying_time = (SELECT MAX(dh2.modifying_time)
                           FROM document_history dh2
                           WHERE dh2.doc_id = dh.doc_id AND
                                 dh2.modifying_time between '2016-09-15' and '2016-09-24'
                          );
```

Notes:

- Don't store dates as strings (such as `creation_date`).
- You should use `between` with dates or datetime.  Your expression probably does not do what you intend.  Write it as `dh.modifying_time >= '2016-09-15' and dh.modifying_time < '2016-09-25'`, which is probably what you intend.
- If you want to keep all documents, then use a `left join` instead of an `inner join` and move the `where` conditions to an `on` clause.
- And `round()` with an integer argument?  I just don't get that one.
- And, as written, the query does not need the `document` table at all, only `document_history`.  You might consider `from document_history` as a simplification.

Comment: All dates are date times, here is an error in the example, I was removing some columns(the table is with 40 columns :)  You are right for the round - it is mistake , I will remove it . I will test your solution, thanks for advices

Comment: I think the range check should be just `dh.modifying_time < '2016-09-25'`. If a stage has been changed last on 09/14 it still has the same  stage in the period from 09/15 to 09/24. And the join with `document` table is probably unnecessary.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel . . . That is a good point.  As written, the query does not need the `join`, only the `document_history` table.